# operator== be a member function or a friend function,?

Tags: c++

Is there a benefit or it is mandatory to make `operator==`, `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator<<`, `operator>>`, `!=`, `>=`, ... as friend and not methods of a class?

I haven't found a good text that explains why go friends way only...

I have a good use case if `C1 x; C2 y; C3 z;` and I have `C3& operator+(C1& , C2&)` as a friend in C1 and C2, i.e when the classes are different, BUT the question is why for the same class.

Comment: Your `operator+` in the third paragraph doesn't seem to make sense -- what is it returning a reference to?

Answer (score 2):

The argument for standalone functions is that these operators should be symmetric according to the operand types. Implementing relational operators as standalone functions instead of methods can have benefits, when your class has constructors that allow implicit conversion of the left hand operand to your class type. Otherwise you would have to write explicit constructor calls or to overload the operator for other left operand types (combinatorial explosion).

The friend declaration is only needed, if you must have access to the members of your class. Since relational operators in general are not expected to change their operands, there are other ways to read members in most cases.

Don't over-use operator overloading. Especially, when you have lots of class types like C1, C2, C3 in your question, it soon becomes unclear, especially for other developers, what your operators mean. Consider having a function with a name that clearly describes your intention.

Answer (score 1):

If your class *has* relational semantics, then make the relational operators part of the class. On the other hand, if you only need something like `<` to make your class ordered for some container, then you might prefer writing a separate, free function for the express purpose of defining that container, rather than imply that this is tied to the semantics of the class (or you could specialise `std::less` for your class).

For the binary shift operators `<<` and `>>`, you may not have a choice, since the member function is only chosen when your class object is the *first* argument of the operation. Beyond that, I'd give the same advice, and I'd make a member operator only if that operation is somehow intrinsic to the class semantics, rather than in aid of some other, unrelated purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Friend functions are preferred because they allow the function to be used in cases like:

```
bool b = (12345 == myObj);
```

This will result in a compiler error if `operator==` is defined as a member function.